# CSV Export from Wordpress | Sourcecode of page in file?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv, export

I'm trying to generate a csv-file from a database in wordpress. 
The generated CSV-file contains the generated database array AND the HTML-sourcecode of the page.

Any idea what a solution could be to get rid of the HTML-Code? 
The strategy with ob_start() / ob_end_clean(); seems not to work.

Thanks for your help.

```
<?php

    ob_start(); 

        $filename = 'provider.csv';
        $headers = array('ID', 'Name', 'Location');

        $handle = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 
        fputcsv($handle, $headers, ',', '"');

        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM provider");

        foreach($results as $results1)
                {
            $row = array(
                $results1->provider_id,
                $results1->provider_name,
                $results1->provider_location
            );

            fputcsv($handle, $row, ',', '"');
        }

    ob_end_clean(); 

    fseek($handle, 0);

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    fpassthru($handle);

    fclose($handle);


    ?>
```

edited: [This is how the csv-file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHPt2.png)

edited: [Screenshot of the solution from aniket patel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H5SY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code I think it will work for you.

```
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $filename = 'provider.csv';
    $headers = array('ID', 'Name', 'Location');

    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
    fputcsv($handle, $headers, ',', '"');

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM provider");

    foreach($results as $results1)
            {
        $row = array(
            $results1->provider_id,
            $results1->provider_name,
            $results1->provider_location
        );

        fputcsv($handle, $row, ',', '"');
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
    exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the CSV file still contains the sourcecode

Comment: Please clear your cache and then try again because it worked fine for me.

Comment: I tried again with cleared cache. But unfortunately it still did not work. But one thing changed: After the database-data is no more sourcecode of the page. But before the database data comes in there is still. (look at my link with the second screenshot)

Comment: Are you sure you were replaced which is given by me because i have double checked.

Comment: Yes, I did and as mentioned there was also a change with your version. There is now just the problem left that there is code from the site in the csv-file before the actual data from the database appears.